# writing in polar form (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

write in polar form this : 
$$
z=\dfrac{e^{2\theta i}-1}{e^{2\theta i}+1}
$$
I use euler formula to get that $z=\tan(\theta)i$

then $\sin(\theta)=\dfrac{y}{r}$,$\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{x}{r}$ that gives 
$$
z=\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{r}}{\dfrac{x}{r}}i=\dfrac{yi}{x}
$$
so I did this last step 
$$
z=\dfrac{ye^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}i}}{xe^{2\pi i}} 
$$
I don't Know what to do next because it lead to last one

Comment: what is *rectangular* form? do you mean the $a + ib$ form?

Comment: Surely you mean polar form?

Comment: yeah polar form, sorry I'm gonna edit that now

Comment: No, I mean to write it in $\cos(x)+\sin(x)i$

Comment: Well you already have $z=i\tan(\theta)$

Comment: is that enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=i\tan(\theta)$, and if $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, then we have $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$, where

$$|z|=|\tan(\theta)|$$

and

$$\arg(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi&,\tan(\theta)\ge 0\\\\\frac{\pi}{2}+(2k+1)\pi&,\tan(\theta)< 0\end{cases} \tag1$$

for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, the polar form of $z$ is

$$z=|\tan(\theta)|e^{i\arg(z)}$$

where $\arg(z)$ is given by $(1)$.

Comment: This answer is trivial because $e^{i\text{arg}(z)} = i*\text{sign}(\theta)$

Comment: @CyeWaldman Yes, it is trivial.  But the OP specifically requested a polar coordinate form.  $i\text{sgn}(\theta)$ is Cartesian.

Comment: Okay, I guess I can't argue with that.